# Optimising T-SQL reporting performance

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012, query-performance

I have the table bellow, I need to delete opposite rows between two dates by pairs based on PerCode Value, 
In fact, we delete rows inside the date range that have the same PerCode and have equal and opposite values.

The problem is that begin date and end date are provided by users as parameters while reporting but the query take too much time if i try to delete these at runtime.

Example:

Begin date = 01/01/2018
End date = 31/12/2018

I should delete rows 3 and 4.
Do u have any idea how to do that while optimising performance (the table have 200 Millions of rows)

```
+----+------------+---------+---------+-----------+
| Id |    Date    | PerCode |  Value  | IsDeleted |
+----+------------+---------+---------+-----------+
|  1 | 01/10/2017 | C1      |    10   |           |
|  2 | 01/01/2018 | C1      |   -10   |           |
|  3 | 15/02/2018 | C2      |    20   |    1      |
|  4 | 10/03/2018 | C2      |   -20   |    1      |
|  5 | 01/12/2018 | C3      |    15   |           |
|  6 | 01/02/2019 | C3      |   -15   |           |
+----+------------+---------+---------------------+
```

Comment: I don't understand why you delete rows 3 and 4 based on the information in your question.  I can see that the SUM of the values for rows 3 and 4 are -20 + 20 = 0.  But there's other rows in that date range.  Row 2 has a value of -10, and row 5 has a value of +15.  The other rows are all outside the date range.  The SUM across all the rows in the date range is actually +5, so I would have expected no rows to be deleted.  There's nothing to explain why rows 3 and 4 are treated differently.  I can see they have equal and opposite values, but this isn't mentioned as being part of the criteria.

Comment: @RichardHansell, thx for you reply
I added the column PerCode to be more clear, rows should be deleted by pairs based on PerCode Value also, so we delete rows inside the date range that have the same PerCode and have equal and opposite values

Comment: Okay, that makes a huge difference to your question!  I mean that fundamentally changes what you are asking for.  There's probably a whole raft of questions off the back of this, e.g. will there always be exactly two rows per "percode"?  If there were three rows for "percode", +10, -10, -10, would you delete the +10 and one -10 at random, or would all three rows be retained?  When you say delete do you mean "set an IsDeleted flag"?

Comment: Yes it can have more than 2 rows per "percode" if so, I delete +10 and one -10 at random as you already said.
In addition to that, delete mean set an IsDeleted flag.
I have already done the query that do that job (the query update the isDeleted column on the table), but I am obliged to apply the query at runtime(reporting time) because I don't khnow the begin and end date before, and this take too much time.

Comment: Can you provide the query that you use already (the one that isn't performant)?

Answer (score 0):

I had a quick go at this, using a table variable to allow me to knock together a query using your test data.  However, this might not perform well when used over 2 million rows?

```
DECLARE @table TABLE (id INT, [date] DATE, percode CHAR(2), [value] INT, isdeleted BIT);
INSERT INTO @table
SELECT 1, '20171001', 'C1', 10, NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '20180101', 'C1', -10, NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT 3, '20180215', 'C2', 20, NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT 4, '20180310', 'C2', -20, NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT 5, '20181201', 'C3', 15, NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT 6, '20190201', 'C3', -15, NULL;

DECLARE @date_from DATE = '20180101';
DECLARE @date_to DATE = '20181231';

WITH ordered AS (
    SELECT
        id, 
        percode, 
        [value],
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY percode, [value] ORDER BY [value]) AS order_id
    FROM
        @table
    WHERE
        [date] BETWEEN @date_from AND @date_to
        AND ISNULL(isdeleted, 0) != 1),
matches AS (
    SELECT 
        m1.id AS match_1_id,
        m2.id AS match_2_id 
    FROM 
        ordered m1
        INNER JOIN ordered m2 ON m1.percode = m2.percode AND m1.[value] = m2.[value] * -1 AND m1.order_id = m2.order_id)
UPDATE
    t
SET
    isdeleted = 1
FROM
    @table t
    INNER JOIN matches m ON m.match_1_id = t.id OR m.match_2_id = t.id;
SELECT * FROM @table;
```

Results:

```
id  date        percode value   isdeleted
1   2017-10-01  C1      10      NULL
2   2018-01-01  C1      -10     NULL
3   2018-02-15  C2      20      1
4   2018-03-10  C2      -20     1
5   2018-12-01  C3      15      NULL
6   2019-02-01  C3      -15     NULL
```

How does it work?  Well I broke the task down into steps:

- make a list of all rows in the date period specified, where they aren't already deleted;
- for each row of data assign it a running count number, grouped by the percode and the value.  So the first C1 10 would be number #1, then the second C1 10 would be number #2, etc.;
- to find matches it's simply a case of finding any value that has the same percode, the equal and opposite value to another value group, and the same running count number;
- where there's a match set the isdeleted flag to 1.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code but this is not performant over 200 millions rows in real time.
and in real life Percode is concatenation of 5 columns (date, varchar(13), varchar(2),varchar(1) and varchar(50)) and Value is 4 numeric columns.

I am searching for other ideas.

```
--DECLARE @table TABLE (id INT, [date] DATE, percode CHAR(2), [value] INT, isdeleted BIT);
Select * INTO #MasterTable FROM
(
SELECT 1 id, '20171001' [date], 'C1' percode, 10 [value], NULL isdeleted
UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '20180101', 'C1', -10, NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT 3, '20180215', 'C2', 20, NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT 4, '20180310', 'C2', -20, NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT 5, '20181201', 'C3', 15, NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT 6, '20190201', 'C3', -15, NULL
) T ;

DECLARE @date_from DATE = '20180101';
DECLARE @date_to DATE = '20181231';

select F.id
Into #TmpTable
from 
(
select Id, PerCode, Value
,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by PerCode, Value order by (select 0)) Rn2
from
#MasterTable ) F 
inner join (
select 
PerCode
, Rn1
from (
select  
PerCode
 ,Value

,ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by PerCode, Value order by (select 0)) Rn1
FROM #MasterTable
where
[date] BETWEEN @date_from AND @date_to
) A
group by PerCode , Rn1
having sum(Value) = 0  and count(*)>1

) B on                F.PerCode = B.PerCode
                  and F.Rn2 = B.Rn1


update  R
set IsDeleted = 1
from #MasterTable R
inner join #TmpTable P
on R.id = P.id

select * from #MasterTable

drop table #MasterTable ;
drop table #TmpTable;
```